# Time dilation and space time

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time

I  know a little about space time, and I know that space time is adding the time component into the three- dimensional world and  creating an abstract universe.

But my question is that why time is affected by the  gravity since time is a relative abstract idea and how it's affected by motion especially when an object is travelling (nearly) at the speed of light?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Buddy my question here is how time is affected by gravity and motion  if it's an relative abstract thing since time has no particles and it's not a kind of wave

Comment: This is a better way to formulate the question. I would totally edit the question like the one in your comment.

Comment: Acid jazz  I am newly introduced to this topic   so can you can explain to me  what is a curved space. Space has no particles but it's a vacuum or medium but I'm not sure if time is ? Space is different from time obviously time is relative while space is not

Comment: This 4d theory is called space time but how gravity affects time? If time has particles that are moving fast and then are slowed by gravity this seems reasonable. but how time could slow down !   But how time is moving  if it has  no particles ?

Comment: In physics, we only have **one** definition of time, i.e "time is that which is measured by a suitable clock". We don't think about in any other way. Time passes,  we measure it with a clock and it's really as simple as that. No particles involved and no philosophy either. The advanced math is difficult enough without worrying about particles of time, if you can **prove** time has particles, you will win a Nobel prize, seriously

Comment: Thank you were so useful but am not arguing about wether a time has a particle or not  . In other word I am confused by the definition of  time in  space that's all , and thank you again .

Comment: @Acid Jazz: You know you made it when they are stealing your material. ;-)

Comment: Don't take it personally, Hoe, Acid Jazz just made a joke about things that I keep saying all the time. Time as "the series of measurements we keep making with clocks" is affected by the state of motion and by gravity. The point that we are trying to make you understand is that time is NOT an abstract notion. It's something that only "exists" in physics because we are making measurements with clocks. We are making measurements with clocks because they tell us a lot about nature. What makes clocks special? All else being equal they all agree with each other about what time it is.

Comment: @AcidJazz: Good question. Given the frequent questions about the nature of time and the equally frequent misconception we should start a pledge drive for "Bad physics definitions you have read in high school textbooks!". You like to ask questions on the site, why don't you ask that one? I promise I won't vote you down or vote to close, even though someone else might. Maybe it should be a meta post? I think it kind of touches on the way we do business here, so we could/should give some clarifying ideas of how to handle those along the line. ;-)

Comment: @CuriousOne It would need to be a meta question. Personally I don't think the serious side of the site is stressed enough, although to "borrow" another quote I saw, the basic questions are sometimes the best and are often the ones that, initially I think I can answer with a (wrong) standard answer,  and then are taken way beyond my level by users out of my league, writing stuff that I couldn't think of and teaching me  how real physics works. I will give it a think.

Comment: @AcidJazz: It's very hard in physics to get to the serious theoretical stuff without an understanding of the basics, so I think it's quite important to give people an idea what physicists actually "mean" when they use a word that often comes with other ("philosophical"! - yaiks!) connotations.

Comment: 1. Personally, **I** know that I need to know the basics myself, often times as much as much as the fringe do. 2. A few times the word ontological has appeared in comments, which "might" be suitable for physics but to me, kills the physics stone dead,  soon as I see it.  Ok,  physics people ask questions, it's in their blood, but there must be a cut off point.  Is it okay to say, on lack of proof grounds, "sorry, I honestly can't answer your question, I would be misleading you". Like I say, I will think of the best meta question I can.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up *time* with *the flow of time*. [Search this site for more on this topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22flow%20of%20time%22). Although we're all used to the fact that for us humans time *flows*, the *flow of time* does not exist in relativity. Time is just a coordinate like the spatial coordinates $x$, $y$ and $z$. We identify points in spacetime by the four coordinates $(t, x, y, z)$, so time is just another coordinate like space.

The phrase *time dilation* stems from the idea of a flow of time - we say the flow of time is slower for the moving object so the flow is *dilated*. Given that time doesn't flow, the phrase *time dilation* is somewhat unfortunate, but I suspect we are stuck with it.

If you take any two points in spacetime then the separation between them is called the [proper distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_length#Proper_distance_between_two_events_in_flat_space) or the [proper time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) (the two names tend to be used interchangably). All observers, however they are moving, agree on this distance but they don't agree how the distance is made up. Suppose I'm watching you move from point $A$ to point $B$. I set up some system of coordinates $t, x, y, z$ with myself at the origin, and in these coordinates I measure your initial position to be $(t_A, x_A, y_A, z_A)$ and your final position to be $(t_B, x_B, y_B, z_B)$. The distance in time you've moved is:

$$ \Delta t = t_B - t_A $$

Likewise the distance you have moved along the $x$ axis is:

$$ \Delta x = x_B - x_A $$

And likewise for $\Delta y$ and $\Delta z$. The total distance you have moved is called the proper distance, $\Delta s$, and is given by:

$$ \Delta s^2 = -c^2\Delta t^2 + \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2 \tag{1} $$

Now suppose you also set up some coordinates $t', x', y', z'$ with yourself at the origin. In these coordinates you aren't moving so $\Delta x' = \Delta y' = \Delta z' = 0$. In your own coordinates you just move in time by some amount $\Delta t'$. You calculate the proper distance to be:

$$ \Delta s'^2 = -c^2\Delta t'^2 \tag{2} $$

But it's a fundamental principle in relativity that we must both agree on the value of the proper length i.e. $\Delta s = \Delta s'$. If we equate equations (1) and (2) we get:

$$ -c^2\Delta t'^2 = -c^2\Delta t^2 + \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2 $$

which we can rearrange to:

$$ \Delta t'^2 = \Delta t^2 - \frac{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2}{c^2} $$

And this means that the change in time you measure, $\Delta t'$, cannot be equal to the change in time that I measure, $\Delta t$. This is what is meant by time dilation. It is not a change in the flow rate of time, it is a difference in how two observers measure the distance moved in spacetime.

Comment: I'm not altogether sure of this, but I've always been under the impression that the word ``dilation'' in this context simply comes from the geometric notion, *i.e.* a dilation transformation as opposed to an isometry: here a nonuniform dilation since the principal directions have different scale factors ($e^{\pm\eta}$ for a boost with rapidity $\eta$), so it doesn't seem too bad a word from that standpoint.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: for the special case of motion at a constant velocity I suppose *dilation* is not too confusing, though even there I think it hinders a proper understanding. Once you consider non-uniform motion (even in flat spacetime) I don't think it's a useful concept.